# How to Generate Custom Archive in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi guys I just want to ask, how to generate an archive list items looks like http://clip2net.com/s/4ZugOE in wordpress

I am new in templating. I tried this one :

`http://wpguy.com/articles/an-archives-page-with-all-the-posts-in-cronological-order/`

but this one return all the post.

What I want is that each month is a link to page of list of items in created in month.

How can I implement this in wordpress with proper php, mysql queries.

Comment: Confused, [check this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index).

Comment: @SheikhHeera:

Thanks for immediate response and for the link. you can check this
http://204.197.252.143/~themainr/premium-content/ 

as you can see in the left sidebar, the list is displayed in years, what I want is that, the link for year is removed but the labels are  remained. And below each year, monthly archived is listed with the link directed to the archived of the selected month.

Comment: if only get the variable month per year, i can use 
`<?php get_month_link( $year, $month ); ?>` to direct the month link to the blog page of articles in the month